# Outbound HTTP traffic being blocked by APF - outbound filter is off

Tags: centos, iptables, firewall, openvz

I'm using CentOS 6.4 inside an OpenVZ container. I'm trying to configure APF 9.7-2 to allow inbound SSH and HTTP traffic (only) and outbound HTTP and HTTPS traffic (don't care much if other outbound works). My conf.apf file is set to the defaults, with the following exceptions:

```
IFACE_IN="venet0" 
IFACE_OUT="venet0"
SET_MONOKERN="1"
SYSCTL_CONNTRACK="131072"
IG_TCP_CPORTS="22,80"
LOG_DROP="1"
```

(Note that I have not enabled outgoing filtering; EGF is still equal to 0.)

When I start APF, I find that any outbound connections are blocked.

```
[root@beta ~]# wget http://www.google.com
--2013-11-19 17:21:02--  http://www.google.com/
Resolving www.google.com... 173.194.115.20, 173.194.115.16, 173.194.115.19, ...
Connecting to www.google.com|173.194.115.20|:80...
```

This does not complete. I can see traffic being blocked by the inbound rule: (I replaced my server IP with 1.2.3.4)

```
[root@beta ~]# grep "173.194" /var/log/messages | tail
Nov 19 17:21:02 beta kernel: ** IN_TCP DROP ** IN=venet0 OUT= MAC= SRC=173.194.115.20 DST=1.2.3.4 LEN=48 TOS=0x08 PREC=0x00 TTL=57 ID=18487 PROTO=TCP SPT=80 DPT=57092 WINDOW=42900 RES=0x00 ACK SYN URGP=0 
Nov 19 17:21:02 beta kernel: ** IN_TCP DROP ** IN=venet0 OUT= MAC= SRC=173.194.115.20 DST=1.2.3.4 LEN=48 TOS=0x08 PREC=0x00 TTL=57 ID=18488 PROTO=TCP SPT=80 DPT=57092 WINDOW=42900 RES=0x00 ACK SYN URGP=0 
Nov 19 17:21:03 beta kernel: ** IN_TCP DROP ** IN=venet0 OUT= MAC= SRC=173.194.115.20 DST=1.2.3.4 LEN=48 TOS=0x08 PREC=0x00 TTL=57 ID=18489 PROTO=TCP SPT=80 DPT=57092 WINDOW=42900 RES=0x00 ACK SYN URGP=0 
Nov 19 17:21:04 beta kernel: ** IN_TCP DROP ** IN=venet0 OUT= MAC= SRC=173.194.115.20 DST=1.2.3.4 LEN=48 TOS=0x08 PREC=0x00 TTL=57 ID=18490 PROTO=TCP SPT=80 DPT=57092 WINDOW=42900 RES=0x00 ACK SYN URGP=0 
Nov 19 17:21:05 beta kernel: ** IN_TCP DROP ** IN=venet0 OUT= MAC= SRC=173.194.115.20 DST=1.2.3.4 LEN=48 TOS=0x08 PREC=0x00 TTL=57 ID=18491 PROTO=TCP SPT=80 DPT=57092 WINDOW=42900 RES=0x00 ACK SYN URGP=0 
Nov 19 17:21:07 beta kernel: ** IN_TCP DROP ** IN=venet0 OUT= MAC= SRC=173.194.115.20 DST=1.2.3.4 LEN=48 TOS=0x08 PREC=0x00 TTL=57 ID=18492 PROTO=TCP SPT=80 DPT=57092 WINDOW=42900 RES=0x00 ACK SYN URGP=0 
Nov 19 17:21:11 beta kernel: ** IN_TCP DROP ** IN=venet0 OUT= MAC= SRC=173.194.115.20 DST=1.2.3.4 LEN=48 TOS=0x08 PREC=0x00 TTL=57 ID=18493 PROTO=TCP SPT=80 DPT=57092 WINDOW=42900 RES=0x00 ACK SYN URGP=0
```

The value for DPT changes on every request.

I've confirmed that outbound HTTP and HTTPS work when APF is off. What do I need to do to make it work with APF on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the problem. The configuration for the container on the hardware node needs to have the correct iptables modules enabled. The default for containers on my server was:

```
IPTABLES="ipt_REJECT ipt_tos ipt_limit ipt_multiport iptable_filter iptable_mangle ipt_TCPMSS ipt_tcpmss ipt_ttl ipt_length"
```

I've overridden this in my container's configuration (/etc/vz/conf/CONTAINERNUMBER.conf on the hardware)

```
IPTABLES="iptable_filter iptable_mangle ipt_limit ipt_multiport ipt_tos ipt_TOS ipt_REJECT ipt_TCPMSS ipt_tcpmss ipt_ttl ipt_LOG ipt_length ip_conntrack ip_conntrack_ftp ip_conntrack_irc ipt_conntrack ipt_state  ipt_helper  iptable_nat ip_nat_ftp ip_nat_irc ipt_REDIRECT"
```

I'm not sure exactly which ones I need, but with this configuration, both the ingress and egress filters work as expected.

I had seen this tip elsewhere on the web, but it seemed to imply you needed to set IPTABLES for iptables to work at all, whereas in my case iptables was working (albeit brokenly) without me having set it.